# Make API calls between Docker containers

Tags: javascript, docker

I am trying to consume the API provided by one of my docker containers (`container_A` let's say) from
a different container (`container_B`). These two containers are in the same Docker network. Before adding Docker I would make the API calls to `http://localhost:{app_port}/{endpoint}` of course, and now that I have Dockerized the app and each service runs inside a Docker container, I read through other questions and websites that you must use the alias of the container (if they are on the same network) or if `docker compose` is being used, use the service name instead, an example would be `http://container_A:8000/books`. I have done this and it does not work. I have configured CORS in all the services and I have also tried to reach the endpoint from *REST client* (which is a VSCode extension that works like Postman) to see if it worked and it did. I did the port mapping / port exposing as well.

Just to give some more context, I want to consume the API from a Node.js app inside a Docker container from another container with a React app inside.

Any ideas of why this would be not working?

Comment: Please describe `does not work`: any errors? What you get when you SSH into docker container and do `curl http://container_A:8000/books`? Is it accessed or not?

Comment: Seems that you have done everything correctly. What exact error do you mean with "it does not work"? Are you sure you are using the right network/aliases/ports/urls?

Comment: @Justinas I use axios to make the requests and the error I get is an AxiosError: ERR_NETWORK the stack is AxiosError: Netowork Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=d78d6b56:1438:14) *Note: My React app is built with Vite

Comment: ERR_NETWORK is a generic error and could be anything. Do the containers see each other on the network? Can you ssh/curl/ping them from each other?

Comment: @EriksKlotins Yes I can ping each other, but not from the React one since `curl` and `ping` are not found... Maybe it is related to the server not returning the proper CORS related headers?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Your last paragraph gives a hint: if the request if being made from a React application, even if it's served from a container, it actually runs in a browser which is outside of Docker space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidMaze 's comment I started trying to use `localhost` instead of the React app container's name since aparently React runs in the browser. In my case, every container's url would look like this: `http://containerName:port`, and when making requests between them I would use that url (since all these containers are in the same Docker network) but whenever I wanted to make a request from the React container, I would use `http//localhost:port` instead.

- *containerName* being the name of the container of your app. e.g:
  `http://webapp:3000`
- *port* being the port exposed. e.g: `3000`

Feel free to edit with more useful information if needed.